# Defining a type in the routes file

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I want to be able to send a JSON to a method on my controller and parse that to an object but to be able to do that I have to define the method on my "routes" file as well.

```
POST    /retornaParametros               
controllers.HomeController.retornaParametros(parametro:Dog)
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't. How do i tell my routes file to accept the Dog object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using Query binder
Refer https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRequestBinders#querystringbindable

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks mate.